# Use filter input to search globally on server in angular ui-grid

Tags: angularjs, search, filter, angular-ui-grid

I am using angular ui-grid to display my data.

I want to use ui-grid's filter input to be used as global search box.
As in, when I type in filter input it should make api call to server.

Comment: ok would you please show your code example i ll tell what is the right way to create this method

Comment: @Ahmer, I am using simple ui-grid implementation as below. <div class="bills-grid" ui-grid="vm.gridOptions" ui-grid-pagination class="grid" ></div> and providing gridOptions enableFiltering: true, which adds a textbox on each column. I want to use those textboxes to be used as a global search, which call a search api on backend instead of filtering local data. So seeking help to find a way to do so. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have something similar on a single column in a grid. That column has the attribute "useExternalFiltering: true".

From columnDefs

```
{ name: 'MyFieldName', displayName: 'Column name', useExternalFiltering: true, filter: { condition: uiGridConstants.filter.CONTAINS }, },
```

Then in my controller I have

```
$scope.gridOptions.onRegisterApi = function (gridApi) {
    $scope.gridApi = gridApi;

    $scope.gridApi.core.on.filterChanged($scope, function () {
        var grid = this.grid;
        var columnIndex = 1; // the index of the column you want to work with
        var termFromMyColumnOfInterest = grid.columns[columnIndex].filters[0].term;
        $scope.loadData(termFromMyColumnOfInterest);
        $scope.gridApi.core.notifyDataChange(uiGridConstants.dataChange.ALL);
    }
}

$scope.loadData = function (term) {
    $q.all([
        YOUR_SERVICE_CALL(term).$promise
    ])
    .then(function (data) {
        $scope.gridOptions.data = data[0];                
    }, function () {
        $scope.gridOptions.data = [];
        // handle error
    });
};
```

I hope that is helpful. For a simpler example, see http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/308_external_filtering